# addToBackStack(), how to add 1 below top of stack

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

The call `addToBackStack()` adds the current fragment to the top of the stack:

```
(current fragment)
Search Fragment
HomeFragment
```

Is it possible to add it  under the top of the stack?
Above Home but under search, like:

```
Search Fragment
(current fragment)
 Home Fragment
```

How could I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: What I mean: show the code you are currently using, too.
And when you read resources on the net already, consider adding links to them for reference. It wouldnt help you when people recommend stuff to you ... that you already found yourself!